# undefined offset but the id seems valid

Tags: jquery

I have a script which scrolls to anchors on the page, it kind of works ( though not 100%), and I keep getting the following problem in the console:

```
TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is null
var divPos = $(theID).offset().top;
```

However if I alert `theID` I get a proper href, e.g. `#l1` but it keeps acting as if it does not recognize it completely.

The relevant code is below:

```
var aChildren = $("nav li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
    var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
    for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
        var aChild = aChildren[i];
        var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
        aArray.push(ahref);
    } // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
        var docHeight = $(document).height();

        for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
            var theID = aArray[i];
            var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
            var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
```

Comment: Can you please set up an example with your html-markup?

Comment: Does `$('#l1')` definitely exist in your html?

Comment: @Djave it does exist.

Comment: @empiric the whole file is quite big, I can't coy the whole thing. If I don't find a solution like this, I will try to reproduce the problem with a smaller markup.